# Calling stored procedure from code-behind

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

[click here to see the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ91b.png)I wrote a stored procedure to get the table value. But I don't know how to write the C# code to call the stored procedure. I want to run it in a console.

My stored procedure:

```
alter procedure sampleone (@createdOn nvarchar(200))
as
begin
    select * 
    from sa_test
    where createdOn = @createdOn
end
```

Sample trial code:

```
try
{
    string connectionString = "(CString)";
    string commandText = "sampleone";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdOn",25/10/2017);
         cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;

         conn.Open();
         int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         conn.Close();
    }
}
catch
{               
}
```

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

<add name="CString" connectionString="data source=34.193.27.161;User Id=sa; Pwd=RCK$1234; Initial Catalog=rs" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>


  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me to get the C# code?

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries, more preferred is `cmd.ExecuteReader();` to return results from SELECT statement in stored procedure. Also "25/10/2017" is a date, why not using `datetime` to pass date value?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: There's no Month 25 with a date of 10. And dates are dates, not strings. Fix the stored procedure to accept a `date` and change the code to pass a DateTime value

Comment: BTW remove that empty `catch{}`. It doesn't help in *anything* and prevents you from finding out what's wrong. The exception would explain that there was a SQL error, or a conversion error, or whatever. The empty `catch{}` prevents *you* from fixing the bug. In production it would allow errors to go undetected and bad data to end up in the database.

Comment: Please add the table definition screen shot  also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo, based on what you really want then your script can look different. However, you should really consider where you want to put your logic. Do you want your stored procedure to insert data or do you want C# to do it? Otherwise here is an example where your stored procedure is used for inserting data:

**NOTE**

> My date is propberly different due to i live in another country - Just change the date back to your desired result and dateformat.

**NOTE2**

> Consider making your createdON variable in your stored procedure as a date instead of nvarchar also.

**SQL Code**

```
    --Build table for test inserts
CREATE TABLE  dbo.testtable (
Name nvarchar(50),
Createdon date
)

--Insert dummy values to sa_test
INSERT INTO sa_test
values('Thomas','2017-10-10'),
('Hans','2017-12-25')

--Edit stored procedure to not just select but also insert data based on @createdOn variable
create procedure sampleone (@createdOn nvarchar(200))
as
begin

insert into testtable (Name,createdon)
    select * 
    from sa_test
    where createdon= @createdOn
end
```

**C# Code**

```
 string conn = "Server=EGC25199;Initial Catalog=LegOgSpass;Integrated Security=True";
 string query = "sampleone";

 SqlConnection connDatabase = new SqlConnection(conn);
 connDatabase.Open();

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connDatabase);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@createdOn", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "2017-10-10"; 
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 connDatabase.Close();
```

**C# Code with datatable and print to console**

```
 string conn = "Server=EGC25199;Initial Catalog=LegOgSpass;Integrated Security=True";
 string query = "sampleone";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 SqlConnection connDatabase = new SqlConnection(conn);
 connDatabase.Open();

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connDatabase);
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) 
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@createdOn", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "2017-10-10"; //Adding the selected items to parameter @check
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.Fill(dt);


            foreach( DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int x = 0; x < dt.Columns.Count; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(row[x].ToString() + " ");
                }
            }
        }

        connDatabase.Close();
```

**Result with console print**
[image]

**Result**

> My testtable is empty at first

[image]

> sa_test table has 2 values i can select

[image]

When i then run my script my testtable looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you,but i need to print the table from c# program console application

Comment: @VinothJS that's not what you asked in the question. plaidDK asnwered what you asked - what's wrong with the code and how to fix it. If you don't know how ADO.NET works, or how to write to the console output or text files, you should be looking for a tutorial, not posting questions in SO. What you ask is the [example used in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples)

Comment: @VinothJS What do you mean by print the table? Where do you want it?

Comment: @VinothJS look at my update - Now its printed to your console.

Comment: Thank u @ plaidDK

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdOn",25/10/2017);
```

should be like this and try :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdOn","25/10/2017");
```

Comment: what is the data type of created on in table

Comment: i changed it..but in catch block shows this error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0".

Comment: createdOn datatype is nvarchar @ShivShankar Namdev

Comment: "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0"@ShivShankar Namdev

Comment: Month 25. Don't pass strings instead of dates

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ExecuteReader` get return data from SP. Also there is TYPO while passing parameter.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdOn","25/10/2017");
```

Updated Code

```
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdOn","25/10/2017");
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;

        conn.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

        }
        conn.Close();
      }
```

Comment: i changed it..but in catch block shows this error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0"

Comment: Month 25? I doubt this will work. *Never* use strings instead of the *proper* type.

Comment: @AmitKumar, no, it's not and you didn't make a meaningful check. It's a string that just happened to be parsed on **your machine only**. What if the database server has a Latin1 collation? This is a very serious error

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this simple technique :

```
try
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CString"].ConnectionString);
    string commandText = "sampleone";

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
            using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@createdOn", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "25/10/2017";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.Fill(table);
            }
}
catch
{               
}
```

Using the above code, your stored procedure data will be populated to the datatable `table`. You can then use this `table` for various use, like processing the data, populating the data into a datagrid etc. Another benefit of this technique is, you even don't need to open/close the connection. That will be done implicitly by the `DataAdapter da`

Comment: changed it..but in catch block shows this error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0"

Comment: app.config file

Comment: app.config <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

<add name="CString" connectionString="data source=34.193.27.161;User Id=sa; Pwd=RCK$1234; Initial Catalog=rs" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    

  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: You didn't tell that you are using app.config. In that case, i guess you have added the required reference and namespace in your class. Anyway plz check the updated answer.

Comment: "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0"

Comment: Better avoid use of `AddWithValue`. Check the updated answer. Btw what is the datatype of `createdOn ` in your database table `sa_test`? Can you show some data if you still have problem?

Comment: That code may work for month 25 in whatever planet that would work. What about month 26 though? *Never* pass dates as strings, no matter what. That's a very serious bug

Comment: then how to pass the date value @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that's why i am asking the table definition and some sample data so that i can suggest him better solution.

Comment: As a *Date* type. Datetime in C#, `date`, `datetime`, datetime2`, `datetimeoffset` in SQL

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir you don't need it. Strings instead of dates is *always* a bug and should *never* be encouraged

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir  besides, if the code throws, it's most likely a conversion error

Comment: @VinothJS - Please show us some sample data of your table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - there is nothing conversion is needed in this scenario. He is telling that "createdOn datatype is nvarchar in the table" and his SP accepts param as nvarchar too!

Comment: createdOn
25/10/2017
25/10/2017
25/10/2017
25/10/2017

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  in my sql server sp executes smoothly and returns the count but i need to run it in c# fron end console application

Comment: @VinothJS - I doubt you are giving something wrong information! Can you please update your post with the screen shot of your table definition and few sample data?

Comment: @VinothJS yes, on your machine, and your machine only. When you try to deploy this to the customer you'll get a nasty surprise. Or if a web front-end is used. That's a career-limiting type of bug. Use the *proper* type. Why use *strings* when using the correct type is *easier*?

Comment: @VinothJS - I saw it already, Please add the table definition screen shot also!

Comment: @VinothJS - Means the structure of the table. You can see it in many ways is ms sql, But for now plz open your table in `Design` mode and take the screen shot.